# How to make two or more IE browser windows share cookies or session

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session, cookies

How to make two or more IE browser windows share cookies or session?

Platform: Windows 7 x64
Browser: IE 9

This seems to only affect local Intranet sites.

For example, I log into a web application on my Intranet and leave the window open.  I open a new browser window and enter a URL that is behind the login, but I am taken to the login page because this new window does not find the session cookie.

So, I explicitly set a cookie for the domain after login and then go through the same scenario above.  The new window does not see the cookie set.

What do I need to do to make it so all IE windows have access to the session and/or the cookies set by the first window on a local Intranet site?

Comment: Unless you are storing ALL session variables in the cookie, and then requesting them in the next browser window, IE Window 2 will never see that session. It's by design. You can open a new window from IE Window 1, and it will automatically see the session because it's the same instance of IE.